# Would it be advantagous to extend android.widget.Adapter in my application?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

In my current application, which is for in-car use, I am displaying a series of Views (which represent gauges) at arbitrary locations within a RelativeLayout (the dashboard). There is obviously an amount of backing data that describes the positioning of those gauges, their attributes, the measurement data that they display, and so forth.

At this point, it would seem sensible for me to create a separate adapter class to contain the code that translates the backing data into the appropriate gauge Views. This would follow the existing Android pattern doing things, whereby various types of View (ListView, Spinner, etc.) accept an appropriate subclass of BaseAdapter to take care of interfacing to the backing data.

What I was considering doing is extending RelativeLayout so that it accepts an Adapter and calls the standard Adapter methods (like `getCount()`, `getView()`, and so forth). My custom Adapter would apply appropriate LayoutParams to each View so that it is appropriately positioned in the RelativeLayout.

So, rather than being a specific question as such, I'm just curious to know whether using the Adapter interface is suitable in this instance. What bugs me slightly is that in the Android library, Adapters seem to be commonly used for Views that present information in a list format. Do you think that subclassing Adapter (or BaseAdapter) sounds like a good pattern for what I'm doing, or is it going against the grain somewhat by using it in a situation where data isn't being presented in a list?

Comment: It's an adapter, I don't think that it being used in a list is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just curious to know whether using the Adapter interface is suitable in this instance

IMHO, no, unless you have an arbitrary number of gauges. `AdapterView` is designed around supporting 0-N children using a recycling pattern to only require a few actual children. `Adapter` is designed around being used with `AdapterView`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's an arbitrary number of gauges and other "widgets" to be displayed; the user will be able to manipulate the number of them at runtime too, and all shall be visible at once. It's handy that you've mentioned the View recycling pattern, as I hadn't considered that, and that's one of the features of the Adapter interface. Though it's undoubtedly not a bad idea for me to implement an adapter utility class, I thought it might be a 'good thing' to implement Android's own Adapter interface and follow its pattern of methods, but perhaps there's no real reason to.

Comment: @Trev16v: Yeah, if they will all be visible at once, `AdapterView` won't buy you anything but added complexity.